# Side by Side R Barplot with error bars

Tags: r, graph, plot, ggplot2

say I have the means of two datasets that I want to plot as barplots with error bars next to each other in ggplot2, or base

Each dataset consists of a matrix of numbers

```
10 20 12
10 20 12
10 20 12
```

which is then transformed into a mean vector of for example 3 elements

```
10 20 12
```

What I want to do is to take both mean vectors and plot them as a bar plot where the first element of one is besides the first element of the other

```
Dataset1Element1Bar-Dataset2Element1Bar Dataset1Element2Bar-Dataset2Element2Bar etc
```

Give each bar an error bar, say of standard deviation. I know I can calculate it through sd but I'm not sure how to stick it into the graph in the proper form

And lastly color them by their element number (ie Element 1)

I have the code to do one dataset but I'm not sure where to go from there.

```
result<-barplot(bardata, main="Mean Coverage",  names.arg=namePosTargetGroup,  ylab="mean Magnitude", cex.names=.4,col=c("red","blue","green"))
            legend(10,legend=c("Group1","Group2","Group3"),fill = c("red","blue","green"))
```

A lot of what I look up gives the answer for one thing or another but its difficult to figure out how to combine them together.

Answer (score 4):

I would generally not recommend plotting just a bar chart with error bars. There are many other ways to plot your data, which reveal the data and its structure a lot better.

Especially if you just have very few cases, plotting means with bars is not good. A good explanation can be found here: [Beyond Bar and Line Graphs: Time for a New Data Presentation Paradigm](http://journals.plos.org/plosbiology/article?id=10.1371/journal.pbio.1002128)

I find it difficult to give you a good solution, since I don't know your research-question. Knowing what you actually want to show or emphasis would make things easier.

I will give you two suggestions, one for a small dataset, one for a bigger one. All of them are created with `ggplot2`. I'm not coloring them by their "element number" but by their origin ("dataset 1/2"), since I find it easier to accomplish a proper graphic this way.

## Small Dataset

Use `geom_jitter` to display all your cases, avoiding overplotting.

```
# import hadleyverse
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

# generate small amount of data
set.seed(1234)
df1 <- data.frame(v1 = rnorm(5, 4, 1),
                  v2 = rnorm(5, 5, 1),
                  v3 = rnorm(5, 6, 1),
                  origin = rep(factor("df1", levels = c("df1", "df2")), 5))

df2 <- data.frame(v1 = rnorm(5, 4.5, 1),
                  v2 = rnorm(5, 5.5, 1),
                  v3 = rnorm(5, 6.5, 1),
                  origin = rep(factor("df2", levels = c("df1", "df2")), 5))

# merge dataframes and gather in long format
pdata <- bind_rows(df1, df2) %>% 
  gather(id, variable, -origin)

# plot data
ggplot(pdata, aes(x = id, y = variable, fill = origin, colour = origin)) +
  stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "point", position = position_dodge(width = .5),
               size = 30, shape = "-", show_guide = F, alpha = .7) + # plot mean as "-"
  geom_jitter(position = position_jitterdodge(jitter.width = .3, jitter.height = .1,
                                              dodge.width = .5),
              size = 4, alpha = .85) +
  labs(x = "Variable", y = NULL) + # adjust legend
  theme_light() # nicer theme
```

[image: Jitter_Plot]

## "Big" Dataset

If you have more datapoints, you can use `geom_violin` to summarise them.

```
set.seed(12345)
df1 <- data.frame(v1 = rnorm(50, 4, 1),
                  v2 = rnorm(50, 5, 1),
                  v3 = rnorm(50, 6, 1),
                  origin = rep(factor("df1", levels = c("df1", "df2")), 50))

df2 <- data.frame(v1 = rnorm(50, 4.5, 1),
                  v2 = rnorm(50, 5.5, 1),
                  v3 = rnorm(50, 6.5, 1),
                  origin = rep(factor("df2", levels = c("df1", "df2")), 50))

# merge dataframes
pdata <- bind_rows(df1, df2) %>% 
  gather(id, variable, -origin)

# plot with violin plot
ggplot(pdata, aes(x = id, y = variable, fill = origin)) +
  geom_violin(adjust = .6) +
  stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "point", position = position_dodge(width = .9),
               size = 6, shape = 4, show_guide = F) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(colour = NULL))) +
  labs(x = "Variable", y = NULL) +
  theme_light()
```

[image: Violin_plot]

## Version with mean and sd

If you insist on plotting the mean with standard deviation, here is how it could be done.

```
# merge dataframes and compute limits for sd
pdata <- bind_rows(df1, df2) %>% 
  gather(id, variable, -origin) %>% 
  group_by(origin, id) %>%            # group data for limit calculation
  mutate(upper = mean(variable) + sd(variable), # upper limit for error bar
         lower = mean(variable) - sd(variable)) # lower limit for error bar

# plot
ggplot(pdata, aes(x = id, y = variable, fill = origin)) +
  stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "bar", position = position_dodge(width = .9),
               size = 3) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper),
                width = .2,                    # Width of the error bars
                position = position_dodge(.9))
```

[image: Bar_Plot]